# jQuery Datatable fnGetnodes not selecting hidden rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

Ok guys, here is my situation, I have an empty table where the user will fill with the rows from a DataTable, this DT is inside a Dialog and this DT can be rebuild anytime depending on the filters.
Each row from datatable has a checkbox where indicate which row he will select to fill the other table, when he hits "add" button, it adds normally (including hidden rows), and the checkbox becomes disabled.
My problem is, when I delete the player from the other table, I need to removeAttr disabled from the checkboxes respectively, but, it doesn't work.
Also, each tr from DT has a class named "jogador##", where ## is an id, so when I remove the player, I can only select the tr, find its checkbox and enable again.

These functions only work with visible rows, nothing happens with hidden rows.

Here is the functions I use:

```
function addPlayer(){
    $('input:checkbox:checked', oTable.fnGetNodes()).each(function(){
        tr = $(this).parent().parent().clone();
        tr.removeClass('odd');
        tr.removeClass('even');
        tr.find('.hide').removeClass('hide');
        tr.find('.removable').remove();
        c = $('#camisa').val();
        cid = $('#categoria').val();
        tr.find('#camisa_').val(c);
        $('#c'+c+'_categoria'+cid).find('table tbody').append(tr);
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
    reactiveSortable();
    sortPlayers();
    $('.dialog-players').dialog('close');
}
function removePlayer(el, id){
    if(confirm("Deseja realmente excluir este jogador?")){
        $(el).parent().parent().fadeOut(300, function(){
            $(this).remove();
            $('tr.jogador'+id, oTable.fnGetNodes()).find(':checkbox').removeAttr('disabled');
            reactiveSortable();
            sortPlayers();
        });
    }
}
```